# Is it secure to mount with defaults my /chroot partition?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, chroot, random, grsecurity

I run debian with GRSECURITY patched kernel.

Apache is chrooted with mod_chroot under /chroot

For now I have mounted /chroot partition with defaults,nodev.

However, Apache need to access /dev/random.

So, is it secure to mount such partition as defaults only?